# How to implement Elastic search on document having several pages

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I want to implement elastic search in my rails application in which I have hundreds of documents and each document has several pages. A user can search within a document for a word. What I did so far is I had created a separate index for each doc and when a user search's in a particular doc the respective index is searched and the results are shown.

Is this the best approach for my use case if not please tell me any other way, also I did everything using REST API call, is there a ruby gem for such functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does the fact that a document has several pages matter ? The concept of page only really exists if you print onto fixed size pieces of paper - not something that is meaningful to elasticsearch

Comment: Sounds like what you are trying to do is highlighting.
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/highlighting-intro.html

Comment: Frederick, pages in document does matter because I have to show the result page wise.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you are expecting on search result.
If you are looking for the page that matched the query , then model your Elasticsearch document as a single page in a work document.
If you want to return the word document as result , then model a elasticsearch document as word document.

Comment: Vineeth, Suppose I model my Elasticsearch document as a single page, so which approach will be more efficient, maintaining a separate index for each doc (will require hundreds of indexes) or a single index for all the docs(will have so many data in a single index). 

Thank you

Comment: Assuming that the number of pages per index is small ( in 1000 range ) , i would highly recommend to keep them as a single index. What is the volume of pages we are looking at ? And how will this grow ? Over time or is the size known at start.

Comment: The number of pages per doc is in range of hundreds but the number of docs are in range of thousands and ill grow with time. In short consider the case U have 1000 docs each doc have 100 pages now which approach in better maintaining 1000 indexes or a single index.